# Media Query for only one Pixel size

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to create a media query for one size only?

```
@media(min-width: 484px) {
      img {
           display: none;
      }
}
```

The example above shows the image will disappear starting at 484px on. Is there a way to write a media query where the image will only disappear at 484px and reappear at 485px without adding another media query?

Also, is there a way to write a media query to do something between two sizes without writing 2 - 3 media queries?

I was wondering if there is a way to write both of these on one line.

Comment: why not just `@media (width:484px) { ... }` ? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Pseudo-BNF)

Comment: why does this not have a selected answer yet tho? Is there any reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why not just

```
@media (width:484px) { ... }
```

?

That is to say:

```
@media(width: 484px) {
      img {
           display: none;
      }
}
```

[Mozilla's documentation for media-query media-features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Pseudo-BNF)

Answer (score 2):

You can chain media queries:

To hide the image for 484px only:

```
@media (min-width: 484px) and (max-width: 484px)  {
      img {
           display: none;
      }
}
```

**Update**

@DaMaxContent provided a better solution. 
Just use width instead of both min-width and max-width.

```
 @media (width: 484px) {
          img {
               display: none;
          }
    }
```

Comment: why not just `@media  (width:484px) { ... }` ? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Pseudo-BNF)

Comment: Also, one being exclusive and the other inclusive is nonsense. *All* ranged media features are inclusive. The given media query will match at both 483px and 484px, not only 484px.

Comment: No worries, you taught me something too :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do like the following code:

**CSS:**

```
@media(min-width: 484px) and (max-width: 484px) {
      img {
           display: none;
      }
}
```

It will hide only at the defined `pixels`.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Mr. downvoter, can you explain, why this solution is incorrect?

Comment: The explanation has already been given *twice*. I'm not going to repeat what others have said.